# glCopyPixels() is not returning the selected buffer pixels

Tags: c++, opengl, juce

I'm trying to copy the front buffer to the back buffer and also I need to copy the back buffer to the aux0 or aux1 buffer, but I can't get it to work. All I get is a blank copy, not the pixels. I do this right after I swap buffers with: SwapBuffers(glDeviceContext);

This is the code to  get the pixels into another buffer:

```
GLint m_viewport[4];
glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, m_viewport);
glReadBuffer(GL_FRONT);
glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
glCopyPixels(0, 0, m_viewport[2], m_viewport[3], GL_COLOR);
```

And I have checked:

```
glGetError()) != GL_NO_ERROR
```

So far no errors. But the result is blank. If I just draw again to the back buffer after SwapBuffers(glDeviceContext) I get the desired result, but it means I have to draw twice. I also want to be able to copy the whole buffer into the AUX buffer for system menus, so I have the background of the whole thing.

Here's a short test code:

```
    GLint m_viewport[4];
    glGetIntegerv(GL_VIEWPORT, m_viewport);
    glReadBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_AUX2);
    glCopyPixels(0, 0, m_viewport[2], m_viewport[3], GL_COLOR);
    SwapBuffers(glDeviceContext);
    glReadBuffer(GL_AUX2);
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);
    glCopyPixels(0, 0, m_viewport[2], m_viewport[3], GL_COLOR);
    SwapBuffers(glDeviceContext);
```

Comment: Did you mean to copy the *depth* buffer instead of the *color* buffer?

Comment: Oops, thanks, typo, fixed that above. And yeah, I tested with GL_COLOR and just now I was testing with GL_DEPTH instead. ;-)

Comment: Also, glReadPixels works correctly, but it's very slow as I have to convert the pixels to an image and draw. I will see how I can do this directly without converting the data.

Comment: The UI is kinda static, as it's a Synth GUI UI. So, I write the background and now I want to draw only portions of the screen. Having a copy of everything in the back buffer is handy as I don't need to redraw things around every time I swap buffers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `glCopyPixels` I recommend using framebuffer objects and use `glBlitFrameBuffer` or drawing a textured quad to the back buffer, instead of copying the front buffer to the back buffer. In general you should treat both the front and the back buffer as unreliable where the contents might become corrupted at any moment. Essentially if pixels in a window don't pass the pixel ownership test, then both the front and the back buffer at that position are discarded.

Comment: Thanks. I will check on those. Still need to learn more about OpenGL. :-) <3

Comment: Sadly glBlitFrameBuffer is missing in my project, not sure why, trying to figure it out. MSVC++ 2017 JUCE Project.

Comment: @WilliamWusikKalfelz: You'll have to load it at runtime. All functions that were introduced after OpenGL-1.1 (i.e. after the year 1996) must be loaded that way: https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/OpenGL_Extension

Comment: Finally got it working with the following:

Comment: `typedef void (WINAPI wglBlitFramebuffer_t) (GLint srcX0, GLint srcY0, GLint srcX1, GLint srcY1, GLint dstX0, GLint dstY0, GLint dstX1, GLint dstY1, GLbitfield mask, GLenum filter);
static wglBlitFramebuffer_t* wglBlitFramebuffer = nullptr;
wglBlitFramebuffer = (wglBlitFramebuffer_t*)wglGetProcAddress("glBlitFramebuffer");`